# How do I use the NavigationLink Properly with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

Brand new coder here and first time user.  I apologize if this is too easy for most.  I am having an issue using the naviationLink to switch from a context view to a detail view.  I want to show a row of of guitars and then show a detail view of the guitar chosen from the table.

Here are some details.  I have a Guitars.swift file that contains a list of guitars. (See below)

```
import Foundation

struct Guitars: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name, description, imageName: String
    }

 let guitar: [Guitars] = [
     .init (id: 1, name: "Classical", description: "This is a nylon string guitar that is acoustic and made if cedar or spruce wood", imageName: "classical"),
     .init (id: 2, name: "Acoustic", description: "The acoustic guitar is a steel string instrument that is traditionally played as an accompanying part of a musical performance.", imageName: "acoustic"),
     .init (id: 3, name: "Electric", description: "This is a steel string guitar that is electic with pickups and made to be played through amplifiers", imageName: "electric_guitar-1"),
     .init (id: 4, name: "Banjo", description: "This is a steel string guitar that has five strings.  It's usually played in country and bluegrass music", imageName: "banjo"),
     .init (id: 5, name: "Bass", description: "This is a steel string guitar that has four strings.  It's usually played in all types of bands and provides the bass line for the music", imageName: "bass")

 ]
```

I have a guitarDetails file that contains a defined property and a struct.  (See below)

```
struct GuitarDetails: View {

    var selectedGuitar: Guitars

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(selectedGuitar.name)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:300, height: 300)
            VStack {
                Spacer()

            }
        }
    }
}

struct GuitarDetails_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GuitarDetails(selectedGuitar: <#T##Guitars#>)
```

And lastly, I have a ContentView file where I created the NavigationLink to move from the content view to the detail view but I can't get it to work.  Can someone help me out?  Here is the content view code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (Guitars) { guitar in
                NavigationLink(destination: GuitarDetails(selectedGuitar: guitar) {
           }
         }
       }
      }
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
  }
 }
}
```

Thee error I get is: "'GuitarDetails.Type' is not convertible to '(Guitars) -> GuitarDetails'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your array of `guitar` and not the type `Guitars` in your `List`. That is why you are getting that error.

Though your naming is not good, you are using plurals for singular items and singular for plural items. This can lead to confusion and it is better to use appropriate terminology for what you are describing.

For example your `Guitars` struct describes only one guitar so it should really be renamed `Guitar`. Similarly the array of guitars is named `guitar` which doesn't make sense as it is an array of guitars so it should really be plural and be named `guitars`.

Ideally you should have something like this; notice I have used a more appropriate naming convention.

```
struct Guitar: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name, description, imageName: String
}

// defining guitars like this, outside of a class or struct, makes it a global variable.
let guitars: [Guitar] = [
     .init (id: 1, name: "Classical", description: "This is a nylon string guitar that is acoustic and made if cedar or spruce wood", imageName: "classical"),
     .init (id: 2, name: "Acoustic", description: "The acoustic guitar is a steel string instrument that is traditionally played as an accompanying part of a musical performance.", imageName: "acoustic"),
     .init (id: 3, name: "Electric", description: "This is a steel string guitar that is electic with pickups and made to be played through amplifiers", imageName: "electric_guitar-1"),
     .init (id: 4, name: "Banjo", description: "This is a steel string guitar that has five strings.  It's usually played in country and bluegrass music", imageName: "banjo"),
     .init (id: 5, name: "Bass", description: "This is a steel string guitar that has four strings.  It's usually played in all types of bands and provides the bass line for the music", imageName: "bass")
]
```

Then your `GuitarDetail` should similar to this:

```
struct GuitarDetail: View {

    var selectedGuitar: Guitar // notice it is no longer plural, as that didn't make sense

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(selectedGuitar.imageName) // make sure you use the image name
            .resizable()
            .frame(width:300, height: 300)
            VStack {
                Spacer()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally your `ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // as you have defined guitars above as a global variable you should be able to access it like this
            List (guitars) { guitar in
                NavigationLink(destination: GuitarDetail(selectedGuitar: guitar) {
                    Text(guitar.name) // you need something inside your NavigationLink for it to work
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I greatly appreciate it.  Now my preview struct in the guitar details file is barking.  There is a placeholder, but I'm not sure what it's expecting.  It wasn't doing this before. Can you tell me what it's expecting so I can run the code? struct GuitarDetails_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GuitarDetails(selectedGuitar: Guitar) . Error is Editor placeholder in source file

Comment: You need to pass in a `Guitar` object. Just pass in `guitars[0]` and that should work

Comment: Dang,  I tried that and it still says the same error. GuitarDetails(selectedGuitar: guitar[0]) . I also tried it with guitars[0] and it give me an error about an unresolved identifier guitars.  This stuff is hard LOL

Comment: It really depends on what changes you have made, you need to make sure that everything is named correctly. In my version of your code `guitars[0]` works, or you can just create an instance of `Guitar` and pass it in `Guitar(id: 1, name: "Classical", description: "This is a nylon string guitar that is acoustic and made if cedar or spruce wood", imageName: "classical")`

Comment: Ok.  I'll try to get it figured out.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I got it to work.  For whatever reason in i passed in the Guitar object, the error message didn't clear like it normally does when the error is corrected.  I tried to run it again and it works just fine.  Thanks a bunch.